# Perforce how to submit file marked as "deleted at head revision"

Tags: perforce

How to add a file, which is marked for delete at head revision? I've tried right-clicking in depot and mark for add (recommended in other question), but that doesn't work and I can't submit. How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If the file was opened by a `Merge` operation, it requires a `Resolve` for you to decide what to do with it (either add/branch it or ignore it -- if you opt to ignore it, then the not-branched file is represented by a "deleted" placeholder file).

If the file was opened by a `Delete` operation, you just need to `Revert` it to cancel the deletion, and then you can `Edit` it normally.

Answer (score 0):

In p4v you can undo submitted changelist. Then in pending changelist view, right click on the file and "Mark for Add". It will now allow to submit.